# What determines what ActiveRecord can rollback inside a change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Recently I made a migration to a column to set a default.

```
def change 
   change_column :table, :column, :integer, :default => 0
end
```

Then i wanted to rollback the change:

```
be rake db:rollback RAILS_ENV=test STEP=2
==  AddDefaultValueToPriceTiersRegistrationCountAttribute: reverting ==========
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration: ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
```

I see reference in the Active Record docs that you can handle changes ActiveRecord doesn't know how to reverse. I would like some insight into how to determine what changes it won't be able to handle. Preferable I would like to know automatically. Something like:

```
rake db:migrate
---- migration successful, but i'm sorry but i don't know how to reverse it ----
```

So again, how can i determine if ActiveRecord knows how to rollback a migration and secondly is there a tool that can inform me if it can't?

Comment: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns

Comment: sorry @BradWerth i heard that `http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns` is not yet realised.? please correct me. i would suggest to read in that case `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Rails to roll back a migration, one of two things needs to be true:

1. Your migration includes `up` and `down` actions which explicitly tell Rails how to perform the `down` migration, or...
2. Rails can infer how to undo changes caused in your `change` migration.

In the second  case, it's more or less common sense: Is your operation reversible? If so, Rails can probably roll it back. If not, Rails isn't magic, and based on the single line

```
change_column :table, :column, :integer, :default => 0
```

there is no possible way Rails can infer what the type or other properties were for this column before the migration ran. If *you* can't tell what was changed by this line, Rails can't either.

Generally, if you're creating something, the "down" migration is obvious: Destroy the thing that was created. If your deleting/modifying something, Rails cannot know what the state was *before* the modification, and cannot roll it back automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i determine if ActiveRecord knows how to rollback a migration and secondly is there a tool that can inform me if it can't?

At the risk of seeming glib, I'd say that tool is `rake db:rollback`

Since a migration can contain arbitrary code, you shouldn't trust that any migration can be reversed without actually testing it.